# XMLHttpRequest is not defined in frontend code

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, frontend, svelte

I get this error from

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    let url = "";

    onMount(() => url = window.location.href.substr(31)); //get query

    xhr.open("GET", url);

    xhr.onload = () => {
        let resp = xhr.response;
    }

    xhr.send();
</script>
{resp}
```

the error is

> ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined

I am using svelte, and all the questions about this error are about backend node.js code.

Comment: Is this an IDE error or a build error?

Comment: it's a build error

Answer (score 1):

first of all why you are not using `fetch` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`?

Secondly `XMLHttpRequest` is not available in **node** so this is probably the reason why you are obtaining this error.

According to [documentation](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount) all external calls should be done in `onMount` hook. Thank to this such calls will be executed only on client side (where `XMLHttpRequest` is available).

Additionally `resp` variable is available only inside `onLoad` handler so it is not possible to render it currently in your code. So it should look probably like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    let resp = 'Loading...'
    onMount(() => {
           const url = window.location.href.substr(31); //get query
           const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xhr.open("GET", url);

           xhr.onload = () => {
              resp = xhr.response;
           }

           xhr.send();
     });
</script>
{resp}
```

But I recommend to do refactor and use fetch.
At the end, it might be more elegant, to work with query params like below:

```
let url = '';
const href = new URL(window.location.href);
const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
if (params.has('paramName')) {
    url = params.get('paramName')
}
```

Mateusz

Comment: While I agree with your refactor suggestion (no point in using the low level `XMLHttpRequest` when the higher level `fetch` is available), the OP tagged their question with `svelte` and `frontend`, so `onLoad` is irrelevant (that's SvelteKit only) and all code is assumed to be executed on the client side, where `XMLHttpRequest` *should* be available.

Comment: I suppose that you meant `onMount` instead of `onLoad`? If yes, then you are right, but I assumed that this question was wrongly tagged. My bad.

Comment: No, you mention `onLoad` as being the provider of `resp`, but 1. `resp` in the OP code is just the name of a variable, which is totally fine, and 2. as I said, `onLoad` is irrelevant here as the question is tagged `svelte` and `frontend`, so clearly not about SSR/SvelteKit (which provides `onLoad`, Svelte doesn't).

Comment: I mentioned `onLoad` because he declared variable `resp` inside it - it was wrong. When he declared variable in the block of `onLoad` handler then it was available only in this scope, so it was not possible to use this variable to render the content. Regarding this, I moved declaration of this variable outside `onLoad` handler.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to adjust your `tsconfig.json` and ensure that `"dom"` has been added to the [`lib` option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib). If for some reason [the DOM type library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts) is not included, the type will be missing, causing errors when using TypeScript.

Comment: dom is in the  tsconfig

Comment: Maybe your build configuration is not using it correctly? E.g. Webpack can be configured to use a different config, or maybe Svelte did not correctly detect it for some reason. Unfortunately there are many ways this can go wrong.